# Migrate iOS app group to another developer account

Tags: ios, core-data

I recently changed my developer account from company to individual. I have successfully transferred my applications, apart from the application groups.

I cannot see anyway of transferring the existing app groups and my thoughts are that if I create a new app group, existing users will:

- Not be able to upgrade
- If they were able to upgrade, their existing data would be lost

None of these situations look good unfortunately.

Therefore in terms of TL;DR:

- How can I transfer app groups between developer accounts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I just spoke with Apple on the phone - they were awesome at helping and we found a solution.

Let's assume account A is the old account and B is the new account that you want to transfer the app group to.

Simply delete the app group from account A and recreate it in account B with the exact same identifier. Problem solved :D Thank you Apple!

Comment: Is there any way to get formal information about this ? We are facing with exact same problem and i am not sure if i should delete and re-create it :) This looks so risky :)

Comment: @dracula Yes I thought the same - there is no formal information online about it, but I worked with the team who they tested internally and said that this is the best approach. If you are unsure, contact them. :)

Comment: Thanks Phil, we are going to try it :) How did you manage share extension or today extension if you have them. Their bundle ID is not transferred. Should we try the same method for them :) ?

Comment: @dracula not sure exactly what you mean? Basically just delete the group, it then opens the id up and then add it to the other account immediately.

Comment: Deleting the groups and additional app-ids (extensions, watch apps, etc.) and recreating them on the new account worked for me today.

Comment: @PhilHudson: Was the data also migrated for you ? I have my coredata sqlite file I am not sure whether that also gets migrated correctly, because I had assumption that iOS sqlite encrypts that file.

Comment: I think you are speaking about something else?

Comment: @PhilHudson - I wanted to know - When pushed app update with account B for that app, were you able to access previous data in app group.

Comment: @Sandy did you managed to migrate also data?

Comment: @Fab: Yes data was migrated too.

Comment: What if Account A's membership has expired? I can't access "Certificates, IDs & Profiles" on account A.